# AutoLayout issue for iPad in XCode

Tags: xcode, ipad, autolayout, swift3, ios-simulator

Whats wrong with my layout? Model in XCode as you see view as iPad 9,7, all constraints on place, looks good. But when I start simulator, on same iPad 9,7, I see such weird screen. What I'm doing wrong?[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an iPhone only app.  You need to make your app universal or iPad only.

Comment: Seriously? There is only one version of Xcode in AppStore...

Comment: There is only one Xcode.  You just need to change a configuration setting. You need to set the Device in the Deployment Info to `Universal` or `iPad`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, Mr. wakama!

Comment: @vacawama if it solved the problem, care to make it answer, so it can be accepted as such?

Comment: Yes, it did solved problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is configured as an *iPhone-only* app.  You need to set the *Devices* setting in the **Deployment Info** to `Universal` or `iPad`.

[image: Show Deployment Info setting in Xcode]